# Pseudospectral method for Rayleigh-Benard with constant temperature gradient

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, fourier-analysis

$$
\nabla\cdot \mathbf{u} = 0 \\
\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial t}+\left(\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla\right)\mathbf{u} = -\nabla p+\nu\nabla^2\mathbf{u}+\alpha g\theta\mathbf{e}_z\\
\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}+ \left(\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla\right)\theta = \kappa\nabla^2\theta+\mathbf{u}_z\frac{\Delta T}{H}
$$

Can I apply Fourier-spectral method for 3D-Rayleigh-Benard convection with a constant temperature gradient in the vertical direction?

I want to take all the directions as periodic.

There are papers which have done this with free-slip boundary condition in the vertical direction using the Fourier method.

But there is a paper that has done it use Lattice-Boltzmann method with triply-periodic boundaries.

Edit:
$\theta$ here is the temperature fluctuation and not the actual temperature.
Knowing that the equations can be solved using periodic boundary conditions.

I'm not sure if the question would be helpful to anyone (since it leaves out some crucial detail).

Comment: What is your concrete question? Just whether one can use such a method? Why would one not be able to use such a method?

Comment: I'll add that it doesn't make sense to make the domain periodic in z-direction, because your temperature profile is not periodic.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth That is exactly my doubt. I have seen papers that use free-slip boundary condition in the z-direction while using Fourier-pseudospectral method. At the same time, there is a different paper that does Rayleigh-Benard simulation in with triply periodic BCs with the Lattice-Boltzmann method. How does having periodic BC in z-direction takes account of the anisotropy, is not explained in the paper and I am confused. Link to the paper:
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c73f/f5284c3b37301f9771552b83b26af83d6e8c.pdf

Comment: I want to know if similar is possible in fourier-pseudospectral method. If no, then why it has been possible for LB method? If yes, then can you direct me to any paper or something?

Comment: I don't know -- I don't actually know anything about pseudospectral methods, I was just trying to understand your question :-)

Comment: Thanks for your time, sir. I hope I have explained my problem to some degree of clarity.

Comment: If $\Delta T$ is constant and you assume $u, p, \theta$ are periodic, you can apply spectral method. All terms in your equations are periodic. @WolfgangBangerth they are assuming temperature fluctuation $\theta$ is periodic which is fine, and the temperature itself does not appear anywhere in the equations.